# How to makes separate sets from objects in `...` in an R function

Tags: r, function, loops, dataframe

In function `foo` below, if a user enters 4 `data.frame`s `a`, `b`, `x`,`y`, is there a way for the function to `rbind` these based on a requested `set.size`?

For example, if a user uses `set.size = c(2, 2)`, then the first 2 `data.frame`s (`a`, and `b`) are going to be `rbind`ed then `x y`
 will be `rbind`ed.

Is this achievable?

```
a <- data.frame(d = 1, cont = T)
b <- data.frame(d = 3, cont = T)
x <- data.frame(d = 3:5, cont = c(F, F, F))
y <- data.frame(d = 1:3, cont = c(F, F, F))


foo <- function(..., set.size = c(2, 2)){

  rbind(... = ...)
}
```

Comment: Sure, but it might be simpler to implement if you have the user supply a single grouping variable to indicate which data frames to combined. In the case of your example, `set.size = c(1,1,2,2)`.

Comment: what is the expected output of foo for  this example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option would be

```
foo <- function(..., set.size = c(2, 2)){
    v1 <- rep(seq_along(set.size), set.size)
    lst1 <- list(...)
    lapply(split(lst1, v1), function(x) do.call(rbind, x))

}

foo(a, b, x, y, set.size = c(2, 2))
```

#### data

```
a <- data.frame(d = 1, cont = T)
b <- data.frame(d = 3, cont = T)
x <- data.frame(d = 3:5, cont = c(F, F, F))
y <- data.frame(d = 1:3, cont = c(F, F, F))
```

Comment: @rnorouzian  Sorry, I missed that part.  It is similar to the other answer

Comment: @rnorouzian  Now, you are giving input as `list` objects instead of `data.frame`.  Not clear about the `rbind`

Comment: @rnorouzian It is not clear how you want to generalize.  What would be the general structure you have as input.  Is it based on removing the "k" element or have to check on `data.frame` objects

Comment: @rnorouzian  May be this helps `foo <- function(..., set.size = c(2, 2)){
    v1 <- rep(seq_along(set.size), set.size);
    lst1 <- list(...);
 lst2 <- lapply(lst1, function(x) lapply(x, function(y)  y[sapply(y, is.data.frame)][[1]])[[1]]);
    lapply(split(lst2, v1), function(x) do.call(rbind, x))

}
;
foo(gg, zz, tt, ss, set.size = c(2, 2))`

Answer (score 3):

Here's an option that uses a "grouping" argument of the form suggested by Joran:

```
a <- data.frame(d = 1, cont = TRUE)
b <- data.frame(d = 3, cont = TRUE)
x <- data.frame(d = 3:5, cont = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE))
y <- data.frame(d = 1:3, cont = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE))

foo <- function(..., ii) {
    ll <- split(list(...), ii)
    lapply(ll, function(X) do.call(rbind, X))
}

## Try it out
foo(a, b, x, y, ii = c(1,1,2,2))
```